# ValidationRule On case object

Tags: validation-rule

I am new bie to salesforce,I am in baffle state whether to go with validation rule or code fix for this scenario.

**Validation Rule scenario:**

**Criteria :** only caseowner has to "EDIT" the case(In Mini Pane Window).

**Analysis :** I am the user, I created a case, my name should display on "CaseOwner" field of case object and i can only "edit" (In Mini Pane Window).the case.
                 If any user try to edit the case,Message should display.
                 If the user "Accepts" the case then "caseowner" field should populate with user name and he has rights to "edit" (In Mini Pane             Window)the case.
Message : Please accept the case inorder to "Edit".

**My workarrounds:**

1. `IF( ISCHANGED( LastModifiedById ) && (OwnerId <> $User.Id) && (OwnerId <> LastModifiedById) && (LastModifiedById <> $User.Id), true,false)` -- Notworking
2. `AND( ISCHANGED( OwnerId ), (OwnerId <> Owner:User.Id))` --Notworking
3. `IF( ISCHANGED(  Owner:User.Id  ) && (OwnerId <> $User.Id) && (OwnerId <> LastModifiedById) && (LastModifiedById <> $User.Id), true,false)`--Error ---The `ISCHANGED` function cannot reference the `Owner:User.Id` field.

Comment: Security settings as Read wouldn't fulfill your purpose? Or do you require explicitly to cover this scenario by using validation rules?

Comment: Mini Pane Window? validation rule or trigger fire for all events you can't control it for  Mini Pane Window only.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in the validation rule:

```
OwnerId <> $User.Id
```

Comment: Why would you `AND` a single clause? Just remove that function!

Comment: @AdrianLarson: You are right! Modified the validation rule.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the below validation rule:

```
IF( $User.Id <> OwnerId , True, False)
```

Hopefully this will work.

Comment: You can *always* replace `IF(condition, true, false)` with just `condition`.